# Zombie Outbreak movie with a cure

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror, zombie

I need help identifying the name of this film.

**PLOT:**

It's about a zombie outbreak somewhere in the city the plot starts then it revolves the surviving group hiding in a cabin until the zombies follow them.
Due to the outbreak, the government tries to use a health patient data to find a immune patient whose blood can create a cure. One woman is immune and a perfect candidate and hence she is accompanied by some men to be delivered safely.

**Plot points:**

1. A woman is immune whose blood can create a cure.
2. That woman is accompanied by a mercenary who is infected but the virus is suppressed due to some drug.
3. At the end the mercenary guy ends up staying and sacrificing himself along with another guy of the surviving group to fight off (using common weapon like a bat or a crowbar) the zombie horde while the woman gets rescued near the boat shore.

**MOVIE YEAR:** Somewhere between 2000 and 2010

**The movies in the following list are not the movie I'm talking about:**

- Resident Evil
- Dawn of the Dead
- Train to Busan
- Doomsday
- Contagion
- [Rec]
- The Crazies
- Berlin Undead
- World War Z
- I Am Legend

Comment: I don't know, but you could go through this list, maybe it will be helpful (sort by year): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_zombie_films

Comment: Is this a Hollywood movie? What language was it in? Were there any recognizable actors, or distinguishing traits like hair color / height / build?

Comment: I am not sure if it was a Hollywood movie. The language was English, I can't see to remember the actors since it was a  while ago and have watched a lot of the zombie films. Although it if helps, it's not in the Wikipedia Zombie list as I went through every film listed in there but some zombie films are not even listed there.  I appreciate the suggestions though.

Answer (score 7):

I believe you may be looking for *[Devil's Playground](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil%27s_Playground_(2010_film))*, a 2010 film.

> After the final stage of human testing goes horribly awry, the test subjects of the fictional pharmaceutical company N-Gen become violently ill. As the side effects worsen, the test subjects become increasingly violent until they are little but marauding beasts. Worse yet, their bites are infectious and in short order London is overrun with hordes of bloodthirsty monsters. Cole, a mercenary for N-Gen and a hardened killer, is searching for Angela Mills, the only hope of a cure for this plague which threatens the globe. As the only test subject who did not suffer side effects, her immunity holds the key to preventing a worldwide apocalypse. Cole's mission is complicated by chaos, continual attacks by the infected, and the virus slowly overtaking his own body.

[This review](http://horror-movie-a-day.blogspot.com/2011/10/devils-playground.html) mentions that "Unfortunately Bart Ruspoli’s script botches this rescue mission plot by keeping her and most of the other characters holed up for the entire second act, killing the momentum and urgency of the situation." which sounds like your detail about them holing up in a cabin.

### Trailer

### Longer Trailer

I found it on [this list of zombie movies](http://upli.st/l/Complete-List-of-Zombie-Movies) which came up while searching for *film zombies cure -"The Cured"*. I did a text search for "cure" and this was the last entry on the list. It mentioned a mercenary, so I looked up further details on Wikipedia, then lifted the trailers from Youtube.

One other thing that might stick out at you, the zombies apparently become good at parkour with their transformation, but reviews noted that only one actor does it, so they show up over and over again.

Answer (score 4):

You may be thinking of 2007's "28 weeks later".  It starts and ends the same as your plot line but the girl with the cure is killed half-way through.  Two other survivors are rescued that appear to be symptom free carriers of the virus are rescued at the end.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/28_Weeks_Later

Answer (score 2):

The plot sounds like [*Open Grave (2013)*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2071550/) where a group of infected people (suppressed by a cure) have the zombie virus, a treatment developed due to one patient (a woman) being immune.

The doctor himself is also infected, the movie opens with him in an open grave of other executed infected and ends with him sacrificing himself to save her from the other 'survivors' as their symptoms return.

Comment: This seems to be set after the period in which the OP believes to have watched it.