# Zombie outbreak movie with a doctor and military team

Tags: story-identification, movie

Not sure when this movie was made but I watched it over 5 years ago.

The plot with a military like base in a zombie apocalypse, there multiple stages of infection ranging from just being sick to being a very dangerous killer zombie.

They have these blood test kits where it immediately tells you if you're infected or not, and they send out teams of soldiers with a doctor.

During the movie they find a child who is immune to the virus and the military team and doctor fight their way back to base. At the end of the movie only the doctor and kid are alive as they approach a gate into the base the doctor gives her hazmat suit to the kid so the guards wont shoot and the kid is brought into the base but the doctor gets shot by the soldiers.

I am fairly certain its not any of these movies:

- Resident Evil
- Dawn of the Dead
- Train to Busan
- Doomsday
- Contagion
- [Rec]
- The Crazies
- Berlin Undead
- World War Z
- I Am Legend

Comment: As noted on the side, this is fairly similar to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/180710/zombie-outbreak-movie-with-a-cure?rq=1, complete with the same list of movies you know it's not.

Comment: 28 Weeks later?

Comment: The Girl with all the Gifts? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Girl_with_All_the_Gifts_(film)#:~:text=The%20film%20ends%20with%20a,sternly%20in%20place%20by%20Melanie

Comment: *Redcon-1* has some similarities too, although the ending is different.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: Extinction: The G.M.O. Chronicles (2011)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The 2016 film, *[Pandemic](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3774802/)*.

> Set in the near future, a virus of epic proportions has overtaken the planet. There are more infected than uninfected, and humanity is losing its grip on survival. Its only hope is finding a cure and keeping the infected contained. Lauren (Rachel Nichols) is a doctor, who, after the fall of New York, comes to Los Angeles to lead a team to hunt for and rescue uninfected survivors.

[This review](https://sorryneverheardofit.wordpress.com/2016/08/07/pandemic/) mentions the ending twist:

> She and her daughter eventually make it back to the base, but by now Rebecca’s daughter is actually wearing the biological contamination suit and the soldiers shoot Rebecca as they believe her to be infected. They message over the radio to the main doctor and he allows Rebecca’s daughter to come into the facility, although he doesn’t know that she isn’t actually Rebecca (who he actually thinks is called Lauren), nor that she is infected. Rebecca dies happily in the knowledge that her daughter is safe.

I think the search terms that found [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/13u3f65/tomt2000_movie_hazmat_suit_with_long_gloves/) mentioning it were `film zombie outbreak immune child hazmat suit` although I had to comb through a lot of false positives before I verified the ending there.

### Trailer